# How to remove string except followed by certain characters with regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove `ab` from a string if `ab` is not followed by `x` or `y`.

For example, if the string is `123ab456`, the result should be `123456`.

If the string is `123abx456`, the result should be`123abx456`.

How could I use regex to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) with a negative lookahead:

```
re.sub(r'ab(?![xy])', '', s)
```

---

```
s = '123ab456'
re.sub(r'ab(?![xy])', '', s)
# '123456'

s = '123abx456'
re.sub(r'ab(?![xy])', '', s)
# '123abx456'
```

---

**Details**

- `ab(?![xy])`

  - `ab` matches the characters ab literally (case sensitive)
  - Negative Lookahead `(?![xy])`

    - Match a single character present in the list `[xy]`
    - `xy` matches a single character in the list `xy` (case sensitive)